# disabe password feature in subclipse (eclipse plugin) to get rid "unsupported password" dialog on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

My eclipse always prompt a "unsupported password" dialog everytime i run it. It causes my eclipse to lag, and sometimes i need to force close it.

This is my subclipse :

[image]

I tried to change the config file in etc/subversion (**ubuntu**), i found it in [this](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-3a1d2d3c54791d2d751794e5d6645f1d77d95b32) document :

```
### Valid password stores:
###   gnome-keyring        (Unix-like systems)
###   kwallet              (Unix-like systems)
###   keychain             (Mac OS X)
###   windows-cryptoapi    (Windows)
//i uncomment and empty the value, like the doc suggested
password-stores =
```

However, the dialog is still there.

Please help me out, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally done it. I'm still unable to save the password but at least the annoying dialog box is gone, forever.

The documentation was wrong, the config file I edited in `etc/subversion` has no effect. The true path is in `/home/user/.subversion/config`. There was actually 2 same config file in my laptop, and only one is work.

The step-by-step syntax in terminal :

1. Chmod the config file because its read only :

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 777 /home/user/.subversion/config
   ```
2. Change your current directory  to the config's directory :

   ```
   cd /user/tama/.subversion
   ```
3. Open it with libreoffice or other text editor :

   ```
   libreoffice config
   ```
4. Uncomment (delete the `#`) in this line :

   ```
   password-stores =
   ```

Uncommenting the second line, with empty value automatically disable the password feature, thus we can say good bye to the annoying dialog box.

Feel free to comment if you encounter a same problem.

Comment: What documentation? I was going to ask if you edited the right file but you seemed to have figured it out.  There is a hierarchy of config options.  Command Line > Per-User > Per-System.  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html